# how to manage width of div according to resolution or browser width without javascript, only in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div "container" which has to be adjust dynamically accordingly with resolution or client width ..

```
.container
{
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:20px;
min-width:1024px;
}
```

When seeing the client width, the paddings used above should be adjust so that, browser do not provide its horizontal scroll bar.

I have tried js(jquery) methods, they work fine. But i have to implement it with CSS only as it would be optimum as sesual.

Comment: What should be the padding and width values at lower resolutions?

Comment: if the width of client is 1366px, the padding should be 40px and 20 px left and right respectively .. and if its 800 or something then .. it should be 0px and 0 px .. hopefully its not a silly demand :P .. the main aim is to fit the content cross resolution

Comment: use media query css to make size adjustment

Comment: try givin the padding value in % rather than px...

Comment: Oh I see you have `min-width` now, my bad. Well, even then, at `1024px` min-width I believe it won't fit 800-1024px viewports. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté sorry, i mentioned 800px width by mistake, the minimum resolution compactible for me is 1024px

Answer (score 0):

Try this

/* put this before the end tag of head */

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {

}

@media (min-width: 720px) {

}
```